# Unable to connect to Azure storage

Tags: visual-studio-2015, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I have to save report to PDF.
I am using this line of code:

```
File::SendFileToUser(stream, printSettings.parmFileName(_fileName + #extension));
```

And getting this error on user screen:

[image: Error image]

Error text:
*Sorry, something went wrong and the file wasn't downloaded. 

Sorry, something went wrong and the file wasn't uploaded. 

Unable to connect to the remote server at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *AzureStorageEmulator.exe* service was not running on the machine.
You should run the Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator on the PC. 
 I was running it through Command Line as *AzureStorageEmulator.exe*